# ILogger instance does not log in async method, but Console.WriteLine does

Tags: c#, asp.net, ilogger

I have a class TCPTransport:

```cs
private ILogger _logger;

public TcpTransport(ILogger logger) {
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogDebug($"Init");
    OnTick += DoTick;
}

public async void MainLoop() {
    Console.WriteLine("Mainloop1");
    _logger.LogDebug($"Mainloop2");
    ....
}
```

When running this class, and calling the MainLoop method, I get the ILogger output "Init", and the Console output of "Mainloop1", yet Mainloop2 does not output at all.

I've tried to put it in a Task, and to make the thread sleep. I can't find any info on why this would happen, I assume it has to do with the fact that the method is async.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft logger ??

Comment: Why is MainLoop async void? That's a pattern to be avoided, as any exceptions thrown within it will be lost and you won't know it failed. Instead, it should return a Task, and then whatever method it's calling it should be awaited. See [8 await async mistakes you should avoid by Nick Chapsas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQu-eBIIh-w) and [Await Async Best Practices by Stephen Cleary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

Comment: Yes, it's intialised from a dependency injected ILoggerFactory, then created using factory.CreateLogger("name"). The namespace is Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: LogDebug and WriteLine maybe writing a different log level message, try changing the _logger.LogDebug to LogInformation and see if the log is written.

Comment: The code is not originally mine, but I have tried running it as a Task it does not make a difference.

Comment: Abdelkrim Bournane's answer worked. For some reason LogInformation does output. Though I am not changing the log level anywhere myself.

Comment: You can check the log level set to your application in appsettings.json file

Comment: I don't think Debug level info is logged by default. Your appsettings probably looks like `"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",` ... meaning "only Information and more severe is logged". Debug is less severe/more trivial than Information

Comment: @MikevanderVelde It doesn't matter if the code is yours or not. Code doesn't care who wrote it. What matters is what was written. This code is not written properly, as any exceptions thrown within it are going to be completely lost. Instead, it should return a Task, and it should be awaited. Please review the links I provided so that you properly understand the implications and can get it corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.Writeline and _logger.LogDebug maybe writing to different log levels. Try changing LogDebug with LogInformation.

If you didn't edit the log level yourself, you can check appsettings.json file for the configured logging settings.

Comment: If the call of `_logger.LogDebug($"Init");` in the constructor is firing, then it's not likely an issue of the logging level being higher than debug.

Comment: It is set to Information in the appsettings.json, and it is working now with LogInformation. So for me this is solved, as to why the first LogDebug is working, I have no clue.

Comment: @MikevanderVelde if I solved your issue, consider accepting the answer.